# Avoiding connect via untrusted certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to avoid HTTPS Connection to connect via untrusted certificate in android?
i use this code for connect:

```
            URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection c = (HttpsURLConnection) u.openConnection();
```

how can i detect untrusted certificate?

Comment: That's how it already works. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to open a connection to an untrusted site with an invalid certificate, `HttpsURLConnection` will generate an error by default like:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not find trusted certificate
```

You should not have to do anything special to enforce this behavior.